# How to find a simple function representing FizzBuzz

Tags: functions, interpolation

Consider the FizzBuzz programming challenge:

> Output the numbers [1, 100], replacing numbers divisible by 3 with
>   "Fizz", numbers divisible by 5 with "Buzz", and numbers divisible by
>   both 3 and 5 with "FizzBuzz".

The case selection can be seen as a function with the domain $[1, 100]$ mapping to values in four non-overlapping intervals; $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$,

$$
  f(n) =
\begin{cases}
\text{something}\in A,  & \text{if $3 \mid n ~\land~ 5 \not\mid n$}   \\
\text{something}\in B,  & \text{if $3 \not\mid n ~\land~ 5 \mid n$}   \\
\text{something}\in C,  & \text{if $3 \mid n ~\land~ 5 \mid n$}   \\
\text{something}\in D,  & \text{otherwise}   \\
\end{cases}
$$

Such a function can be trivially found with e.g. polynomial interpolation by letting each interval contain only a single number.

However, how does one find such a function that is as "simple" as possible? "Simple" is a bit vague, but in the case of a polynomial the number of terms would be a good measure.

Are there any other ways to construct such a function (without using cases)? Preferable a so "simple" function as possible.

Comment: $f(n)=(n^{4}\bmod {15}$) goes to $A=\{6\},B=\{10\},C=\{0\},D=\{1\}$

Comment: The "natural" definition of this function is that it is periodic - $f(n+15)=f(n)$ for any integer $n$. That's gonna be a bad idea to try to approximate with a polynomial. You could try $f(n)=\sin 2\pi\frac{n^4}{15}$, which will gives something which works for all $n$. You might also try a Fourier series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using number theory, you can say:

$$f(n)=n^{4}\bmod {15}$$ going to $$A=\{10\},B=\{6\},C=\{0\},D=\{1\}$$

If you want something more "continuous," you could take, for example, $$f(n)=2\cos (2\pi n/3)-\cos(2\pi n/5)$$

$$A=[1.65,2.85],B=[-2,-2], C=[1,1], D=[-1.31,0]$$

The best approach is to use trig functions, since $f$ is inherently periodic.

A discrete Fourier transform gives us an "exact" function:

$$f(n)=\frac{13}{15}+\frac{2}{5}\left(\cos 2\pi n/5+\cos 4\pi n/5\right)+\frac{4}{3}\cos(2\pi n/3)$$
Then we get $A=\{2\},B=\{1\},C=\{3\},D=\{0\}.$ You can expand those to make them intervals.